# Creating a Test Page For a Test User in Facebook Graph Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a test page for the test user i created in my Facebook application portal, i added the `manage_page` permission to the test user and aquired an access token as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-pages).

However, i'm using the Facebook graph explorer to make a post request to `user_id/accounts` with the following parameters:

```
**name** Test Page
**about** This is a test page
**category_enum** LITERARY_ARTS
**picture** https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg 
**cover_photo** http://healthhub.co/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Group-Slider.jpg
```

i'm getting the following invalid parameter error on the cover picture , i tried to encode the URL but didn't help.

> {   "error": {
>       "message": "(#100) Params cover_photo with a valid URL is required for creating a page",
>       "type": "OAuthException",
>       "code": 100,
>       "fbtrace_id": "A35OXtKL8zh"   } }

Answer (score 1):

cover_photo is an object that expects the URL parameter and the URL as value:

```
{
  "url": "<URL VALUE>"
}
```